# Convert first letter from lowercase to uppercase URLs using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert example.com/test/test2 to example.com/Test/Test2.
Using .htaccess or apache (2.4) rewritemap.

I found a lot of options, but they all change all the letters in the word, how to increase only the first letter after each "/"

Will really appreciate your kind answers.

I have tried following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond expr "toupper(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#(.+)/?$#"
RewriteRule [a-z] %1/ [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add whatever you tried in your question(there is nothing right or wrong here, we are all here to learn), which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: I have tried this method I tried this method but it converts all characters to uppercase `code`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond expr "toupper(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#(.+)/?$#"
RewriteRule [a-z] %1/ [L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found a lot of options, but they all change all the letters in the word, how to increase only the first letter after each "/"

First define this `RewriteMap` in your Apache config and restart the web server.

```sh
RewriteMap uc int:toupper
```

Then use rule in your site root .htaccess to convert first letter after each `/` to uppercase.

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Z].*/)?([a-z])(.*) /$1${uc:$2}$3 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.

---

**Update:** Based on comment below to uppercase only in the first two subdirectories use:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Z][^/]+/)?([a-z])(.*) /$1${uc:$2}$3 [R=302,L]
```